# Post array of inputs as object to controller, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have ModelView

```
public class GoalView
{
    public int MandatoryGoalID { get; set; }
    public string MandatoryGoalName { get; set; }
    public string MandatoryGoalTarget { get; set; }
}
```

my view with a list of inputs:

```
                    @foreach (var item in Model.MandatoryGoals)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="MandatoryGoalName[]" value="1">@item.GoalName</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="40">
                                <input disabled type="text" name="MandatoryGoalTarget[]" style="width: 40px;" value="@item.GoalTarget" class="form-control input-sm">
                                <input type="hidden" value="@item.ID" name="MandatoryGoalID[]">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

JS code

```
             var userGoals = {
        MandatoryGoalID : $('input[name="MandatoryGoalID[]"]').serialize(),
        MandatoryGoalName : $('input[name="MandatoryGoalName[]"]').serialize(),
        MandatoryGoalTarget : $('input[name="MandatoryGoalTarget[]"]').serialize()
        };

    $.post('/Home/UpdateGoals', $.param(userGoals), function (data) {
    });
```

Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateGoals(List<GoalView> userGoals)
    {


        //return Content(userGoals.First().MandatoryGoalName);

        return Content("");
    }
```

Controller receive null object. What is wrong here? I need to receive an array of object GoalView.

Please help :)

**Updated**

Ok, i've fixed problem with list of objects in JS

```
    var mandatoryTargetsValues = new Array();
    $('input[name="MandatoryGoalTarget[]"]').each(function () {
        mandatoryTargetsValues.push($(this).val());
    });
    var mandatoryNamesValues = new Array();
    $('input[name="MandatoryGoalName[]"]').each(function () {
        mandatoryNamesValues.push($(this).val());
    });
    var mandatoryIDValues = new Array();
    $('input[name="MandatoryGoalID[]"]').each(function () {
        mandatoryIDValues.push($(this).val());
    });


    console.log(mandatoryTargetsValues);
    console.log(mandatoryNamesValues);
    console.log(mandatoryIDValues);

    var ListOfMandatoryGoals= Array();

    var i;
    var obj = {};
    for (i = 0; i < mandatoryTargetsValues.length; ++i) {
        obj.MandataryGoalID = mandatoryIDValues[i];
        obj.MandatoryGoalName = mandatoryNamesValues[i];
        obj.MandatoryGoalTarget = mandatoryTargetsValues[i];
        ListOfMandatoryGoals.push(obj);
    }

    console.log(ListOfMandatoryGoals);

    $.post('/Home/UpdateGoals', $.param(ListOfMandatoryGoals), function (data) {
    });
```

This code created array with all objects
But still controller receive NULL
Please help with it

Screenshot of object in Web console

[image]

Comment: sending an object but receiving as List of objects?

Comment: please advise ho to do in correctly, What I have - a list of inputs and checkbox - this is list of "Objects". How is it correctly to send and receive ?

Comment: `userGoals` is a single JS object. Then it contains one property "MandatoryGoalID". This property contains an array listing all the IDs from your various ID inputs. Same for the other properties. The structure of your JS object is all wrong. Try running `console.log(JSON.stringify(userGoals));` to see the structure and you'll see how it doesn't match what you need. You are sending one badly-formed object to the controller instead of a list of objects. I think if you just serialize the entire form in one go you'll have better luck

Comment: ok good. I've never need to use $.param to send anything to MVC. Try with just sending ListOfMandatoryGoals without the $.param around it

Comment: incidentally, if you are using this for ajax, your controller should really return a JsonResult, not an ActionResult. Otherwise when you get to the point of sending content back, it will try to send back an entire View with all the HTML markup (including head, body etc) which I doubt you want.

Comment: ahhh, problem is fixed, thanks, but I have another question, what to do if I need to send a few other list of objects in one reqeust? And my controller method looks like -    public JsonResult UpdateGoals(List<GoalView> mandatoryGoals, List<GoalView>  userGoals, List<GoalView>  newGoals)
        {

Comment: you should just be able to send them as a comma separated list I think, e.g, `data: { JSON.stringify(ListOfMandatoryGoals), JSON.stringify(userGoals), JSON.stringify(newGoals) }`. If that doesn't work, make a new ViewModel class in C# that contains all of the different lists, and use that as the parameter for the controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem  is fixed,

correct AJAX request -

```
      $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/UpdateGoals',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(ListOfMandatoryGoals)
    });
```

List of objects is in updated start post

Thanks